# How to undisable input with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, disabled-input

I'm using `react-hook-form` and I want to set disable to false in one input when I'm typing anything in another input.

my code is (only part of it ofc.):

```
         <label htmlFor="channel">Channel</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="channel"
            id="channel"
            {...register("channel", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "channel is requires",
              },
            })}
          />
```

```
         <label htmlFor="twitter">Twitter</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="twitter"
            id="twitter"
            {...register("social.twitter", {
              disabled: !dirtyFields.channel,
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "twitter account is required",
              },
            })}
          />
```

it does infinity loop after typing sth in "twitter" input. its becouse of `!dirtyFields.channel`, when it turn into false, then whole app crashed, but I dont know why, can someone help me with that?

I used watch and touchedFields, but it is this same situation

Comment: Hello, it looks like your component trigers to re-render. 
If I were you I would try to remove the register functions out of JSX, and or put them in a memo, having to the last register a dependency of the dirtyFields.channel.
Then you can spread the register results using the mem variables.

Comment: it works! thank you a lot!